# How can I bind dynamic xml file to asp tree view?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, data-binding, treeview

I am trying to bind information from a web service to a tree view in my asp.net website. Using a drop down list, I choose a stock symbol that retrieves that company's information from the web service. I am currently outputting that information as a string.

What I am trying to do is bind it to a tree view dynamically. This is where I'm at:

My aspx.cs file..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using net.webservicex.www;
using System.Xml;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private net.webservicex.www.StockQuote StockQuote;
    private string StockInfo;
    private XmlDocument stockDoc = new XmlDocument();



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string symbol = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        StockQuote = new net.webservicex.www.StockQuote();
        StockInfo = StockQuote.GetQuote(symbol);
        stockDoc.LoadXml(StockInfo);
        test.Text = StockInfo;


    }
}
```

I cannot configure the data source in design view because it's dynamic, and I never used a hierarchical scheme. Do I need to do that? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `XmlDataSource` and set it's `DataFile` property to the desired Xml file. Now go to your `TreeView` and set it's `DataSourceID` to the ID of `XmlDataSource` object.

**Update**
I just noticed that you are getting your Xml from a service. In that case use the `Data` property of `XmlDataSource` object to set the data xml.

**Update**
Declare your `XmlDataSource` in the aspx markup and set it as the `DataSourceID` of the `TreeView` (again in the markup). In the code behind (in an appropriate event), do something like below.

```
xmlDataSource.Data = StockInfo; // StockInfo is your string variable
treeView.DataBind(); // i am not sure whether this is necessary
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I go about using the Data property?  This is my first time trying to do it through a service.  I am used to just using a sql database as my source.  I appreciate your time!